# is the set of a discrete metric where the distance is constant considered empty

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, metric-spaces

Just wondering what {y belongs to X such that d(x,y)=k} where k belongs to (0,1] is on the normal discrete metric space

Is this set considered empty. If so at what values of k

Thanks

Comment: Is $x$ some fixed point in $X$? And are you fixing $k$, or is your set $\{y \in X \,|\, \exists k \in (0,1], \, d(x,y)=k \}$?

Comment: x is a fixed point in X and I am trying to find what values of k make this set empty

Comment: $k \in (0,1)$ definitely would make the set empty, since all distances are $0$ or $1$. For $k=1$, do you know when the set would/wouldn’t be empty?

Comment: Im not too sure, For the k=1 case would this be empty as well? My rationale is visualising it as a circle boundary and with a const radius k. I believe that boundary is empty as well but I'm not quite sure. Is this the correct way to approach the problem?

Comment: Do you know the definition of the discrete metric?

Comment: Yes, I'm just not too sure how to approach the k=1 value. I don't really have a good intuition or visualization of the discrete metric space

Comment: I can help you with the $k=1$ value, but first use the definition of the discrete metric to say which $y \in X$ have $d(x,y)=1$.